# Artificial gravity in spinning space station, suspended frame of reference

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, reference-frames, centrifugal-force

If I'm inside spinning space station designed to create artificial gravity (and the station is a vacuum, so no air resistance), but I'm suspended, not touching any wall, with the same directional velocity as the center of the space station, do I just float there?

When do I transition into the same frame of reference that generates the artificial gravity?

Is it when I touch the outside edge and the friction accelerates me to the spinning wall of the station?

[image]

Comment: Or you smack into an internal partition...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why would a spinning space station create a centrifugal force on an astronaut rather than simply spinning around him/her?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/257848) or [Would you feel Centrifugal Force without Friction?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/285922)

Answer (score 1):

The artificial gravity comes from the centripetal force from the floor to the object and which causes the object to rotate.  So you won't have any such artificial gravity unless you were on the interior surface and rotating along with the surface.